# Haproxy ability for multiple port 80, 443 frontends

Tags: haproxy

I have the need to have both layer7 and layer4. An api where i divert requests two 2 different backends. one backend for GET requests and one backend for PUT,GET & DELETE requests. That being my layer 7 front end.

The layer4 front to handle websites who make the api requests. They just split round robin.

Layer7 was working consistently before I add in this layer4 section, ie just did our loadbalancing for the api. As i migrate the websites w/ the layer4 frontend, api requests, ie layer7, get lost sometimes but not always.

**As you can see, sometimes request is lost, sometimes works:**

```
[richv@lb2 ~]$ curl api
curl: (52) Empty reply from server                   <-- this is not ok, http 503
[richv@lb2 ~]$ curl api
{"error_code":256,"error_message":"No Site specified"}  <-- this is ok, cause didnt give all the headers.
```

**Front ends are:**

```
frontend layer7-http-listener
bind *:80
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/httpd/certs/haproxy.pem
mode http
option      httpclose
option      httplog
option      forwardfor
option accept-invalid-http-request

frontend layer4-listener
bind *:80  transparent
bind *:443 transparent
bind *:3306
mode tcp
option      tcplog
```